# How do I move the table to the vertically center ? , and align figure and table together

Tags: tables, subfloats

```
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figure/ch3/result_s2/book.jpg}}
    \qquad \qquad
        \scalebox{0.7}{
    \begin{tabular}[c]{cc}
    \hline
      \textbf{Method} & \textbf{$\sigma$} \\ \hline
      method 1 & 0.0 \\
      method 2 & 0.1 \\
      method 3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{figure}
```

Please help!, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you place the graphic inside a `minipage` of width `0.5\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/ch3/result_s2/book.jpg}
 \end{minipage}%
 \hspace{4em}% easier to read than "\qquad\qquad", right?
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline
      \textbf{Method} & \textbf{$\sigma$} \\ 
      \hline
      method 1 & 0.0 \\
      method 2 & 0.1 \\
      method 3 & 0.2 \\ 
      \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have use \hfil instead of \hspace{4em}, assuming you wanted to center the tabular in the remaining space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - I must confess I wasn't sure I fully understood the OP's objectives. I assumed the posting was mostly about how to position the two objects vertically centered relative to each other. Maybe the OP will still weigh in with a more detailed statement of his/her objectives.